# Does urllib in python support interaction with text boxes and buttons on a webpage? If not , are there any modules that support this?

Tags: python, web-services

I cant seem to find out how to put text into a text box on a webpage then activate a button. I've tryed seeing if urllib supports this but I've noticed it only supports reading and not writing. So are there any modules that support writing in a text box and activation of buttons on a webpage using python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python To Interact with Webpages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940033/using-python-to-interact-with-webpages)

Comment: urllib only send, receive data - it doesn't render page so it doesn't know what text box is.

Comment: when you put text into text box and press button then browser send this data to server - and urllib can send this data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution you're looking for is called [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), which has a [python binding](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to work interactively with web pages. You can use a variety of browser clients with WebDriver, including FireFox, Chrome, and IE, along with my favorite: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which is a headless browser that works great with server apps.

See the article on https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/ for a quick introduction.